# c# How to make a button ignore panel vertical scrollbar?

Tags: c#, button, scrollbar

I have a panel on which I placed some ComboBoxes , 2  Buttons and a Scrollbar. I want my buttons to stay where they are, while ComboBoxes will follow the Scrollbar. So far, I've found one solution, on my first Panel I added another one, where I placed my buttons but it's kind of weird. Is there any other solution?

Comment: I would vote for the solution you mentioned: move the two buttons to their own panel. Having some controls on a panel react to a scroll bar but some not is kind of unorthodox behavior.

Comment: Yes, as I wrote above I made second Panel and placed my buttons there, but I was wondering if there were any other solutions. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the buttons outside the `Panel`; right below it. You can then set their [`Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property as well to ensure they move when the `Form` is resized. That being said, you'll want to set the `Anchor` property of the `Panel` appropriately as well.